# Extracting .cab files

Tags: c#, cab

I want to extract all .cab files inside a particular folder in c# .net

```
static int ExtractCabFiles()
    {



        try
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Extracting Cab files");
            string strCommand = @"extrac32.exe";
            var strArrCabDetails = new string[3];
            strArrCabDetails[0] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cab_Files_Path"];
            strArrCabDetails[1] = "/L";
            strArrCabDetails[2] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Event_Files_Folder_Path"];

            WriteLog("Cab files path : " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Cab_Files_Path"] + "", false, false);

            const string strArgsSeparator = " ";
            string strArgs = string.Join(strArgsSeparator, strArrCabDetails);

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = strCommand;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = strArgs;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            WriteLog("Extract Command : " + strCommand + " " + strArgs + "", false, false);
            process.Start();

            //string strError = process.StandardError.ReadLine();
            iExitCode = process.ExitCode;


             }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

This code will extract a single .cab file but I want to extract multiple .cab files from the folder.

Comment: IIRC, there are libraries that will do this without having to invoke a process.

Comment: That's nice. Do you have any problem or you're just notifying us of your intent?

Comment: Just get the files in the folder using Directory class and loop over them invoking extract32

Comment: Oscar do u have any sample code??

Comment: @Taosique yes I have an issue, I want extract more then one cab file that are present in a folder

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I faced the same problem

To extract multiple files just use a wild card and the **expand** command e.g.

**expand** "C:\InputFolder*.CAB" -I -F:* C:\OutputFolder

the **-I** is necessary if you want the file with the original name. Otherwise it will maintain the original CAB name(at least its what happens when the cat file only have one file). What i mean is if the name of the file is file.CAB the name of the output will be file.CAB and  not file.txt  asuming that the CAB file only have one file named file.txt. If you want to preserve also directory structure, change **-I** to **-R**